# Maintain global resource in Django

Tags: python, django

I am writing a prototype system involving some Natural Language Processing.
So I am using the Stanford parser in nltk.

So in the view function, I will call a function which will load the parser, and parse a sentence. But repeatedly loading this parser is totally a waste of resource and time. Is there any way to maintain the parser in a global scale, and just use it anytime I want.

```
os.environ['STANFORD_PARSER'] = os.path.join(
    os.path.expanduser('~'), 'stanford-parser/stanford-parser.jar')
os.environ['STANFORD_MODELS'] = os.path.join(
    os.path.expanduser('~'), 'stanford-parser/stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar')
parser = nltk.parse.stanford.StanfordParser(
    model_path="edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz")
parsed = parser.parse(sentence_which_differs_from_time_to_time)
```

Comment: Does adding it to the settings.py file not work well enough?

Comment: Thanks, that should work. But as this is app specific, or even on a smaller scale, it would be better if there is a way to control its scope. Is there a way to maintain it in the memory but not global? Or add a global variable in a view file rather than 'settings.py', so for readability's sake.

Answer (score 0):

Put the parser creation code at the module level (e.g. in `views.py`) instead of inside the function. It will get called once, when the module is first imported.

Of course, depending on how your server works, there will probably be multiple instances running, so the code will run each time a new process is started. If startup time were a real concern, you would probably want to look into running it in a separate process and using IPC.

But usually it's sufficient to just run the code at module import time.